# How will you solve the following recurrence equation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

$$\mathrm{T}(n)=\begin{cases} 1 & n=1 \\ 3\cdot \mathrm{T}(n/4)+1 & n>1 \end{cases}$$
I got to:
$$3^k\cdot \mathrm{T}(n/4)+3^{k-1}+3^{k-2}+\cdots+3+1$$

Can someone please help me?

Comment: The Master theorem comes to mind.

Comment: we get $$T(n)=c_1 3^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (4)}-1}+\frac{1}{2} \left(3^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log
   (4)}}-1\right)$$

Comment: can you give the big O notation of this final equation?

Comment: Start with $S(n) = T(4^n)$, and find a closed form for $S$.